# Facebook API - Insights: Status: 500, error code 1, "An unknown error occurred" at random times

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

Of the late when trying to fetch data from FB's Marketing API, I get following error:

> ```
>   Status:  500
>   Response:
>     {
>       "error": {
>         "code": 1,
>         "message": "An unknown error occurred"
>       }
>     }
> ```

at times. If I try to immediately make the same request via Postman, it returns data at times and at times throws 500 status error.
Below is the data being sent to FB

```
  facebookads.exceptions.FacebookRequestError:

  Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  GET
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/act_XYZ/insights
  Params: {
      'time_increment': 1,
      'level': 'adgroup',
      'fields': '["account_name", "deeplink_clicks",
                  "campaign_name",
                  "social_impressions",
                  "campaign_group_name",
                  "campaign_id",
                  "adgroup_name",
                  "unique_impressions",
                  "social_reach",
                  "unique_social_impressions",
                  "placement",
                  "total_actions",
                  "cpm",
                  "impressions",
                  "ctr",
                  "reach",
                  "clicks",
                  "social_clicks",
                  "spend",
                  "website_clicks",
                  "adgroup_id",
                  "actions",
                  "cpc",
                  "cpp",
                  "unique_clicks",
                  "app_store_clicks",
                  "unique_social_clicks",
                  "account_id",
                  "campaign_group_id"
              ]',
  'breakdowns': '["placement"]',
  'time_range': '{"since":"2015-09-01","until":"2015-09-09"}',
  'summary': None
  }

  Status:  500
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "code": 1,
        "message": "An unknown error occurred"
      }
    }
```

I am using Facebook's Python SDK from

> -e git+https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk.git@449f56f0db086a41bedd23df714e7f77c1051f5b#egg=facebook_sdk-dev

Can someone please let me know what I might be missing in this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I'm running into the same issue and I have noticed a pattern where it errors out when the request takes more than ~30s in Postman.  Not sure what you can do to fix this but I have had some success by:

- Pulling back the level of granularity / breakdowns
- Limiting to a lower # of records per page

Unfortunately I haven't seen a consistent pattern with the levels of granularity that cause this delay.  Sometimes I can report @ ad level with 5000 results per page, other times I need to throttle back significantly

Answer (score 1):

You may want to learn about the HTTP protocol - in this case about [response status codes](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html). 500 means "internal server error", IOW it's the facebook API server that failed, not your code. Your only options at this point are to either log the error and call it a day or setup a wait/retry loop.

Comment: I know Status Code 500 is Internal Server Error.
I was hoping that it might be some known edge case I can try and avoid.
I guess, a wait-retry is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this problem as well and noticed that it seems to be particular to looking for campaign_name and campaign_id.  I've had a consistent success/fail based on excluding or including those fields.

I'm using Ruby and accessing the v2.5 insights api.

#### Update

So I just tested playing with setting vs. not setting level to campaign when asking for the campaign_name field and when I set the level to campaign the call is now successful.  Maybe try setting your level differently to test?

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing the same problem.  The inights ran at the ad account level is definitely the most performant from "our" end.  I've put in conditional exception handling on the insights call to the adaccount and if that returns an exception from facebook after the api calls have been initiated then I try grabbing all campaigns and run insights against each campaign.

This also helps prevent the execution limit by only calling one insights api call per account if it can and only go into the campaign granularity of insight calls if the adaccount call fails.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).